# Is there a way to render DRM content with WebGL?

Tags: javascript, browser, webgl, drm

I'm currently trying to draw some DRM content with WebGL. I've already managed to draw normal and simple content without DRM but drawing DRM content only displays a black screen. I'm following these functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texSubImage2D in order to render my stuff. Does someone know why? Has someone tried this before? Thank you!

```
this._gl.bindTexture(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, webGLTexture);

 this._gl.texSubImage2D(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, this._gl.RGBA,
        this._gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, video);

 this._gl.bindTexture(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

On many devices DRM will leverage a secure media path - this is designed to ensure that encrypted video content is decrypted and displayed directly to the screen without any other application, or even the OS, being able to access the decrypted video.

On some devices it is possible to do some basic manipulations to support, for example, VR but these will usually not allow any read option.

If your use case is to display DRM protected video inside a webGL created 'world' then this is possible on many/most devices - typically you would add a secure or protected view or window into your generated world and play the encrypted video in that view.

Comment: What if WebGL does not support the creation and manipulation of protected textures?

Comment: Do you mean protecting for example a 3D model itself? AFAIK, currently there are no mainstream DRM techniques to protect models and allow them be manipulated.

Comment: No, I mean creating a protected content (or texture) inside WebGL, like this OpenGL extension: https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/EXT/EGL_EXT_protected_content.txt

Comment: Could you post your code and also the browser console output to the question also - if the issue is with the DRM license there will usually be a log to the console.

Comment: There is no abnormal errors. The video is accessed correctly as I can actually hear the video. I will edit my post in order to show my drawing code but, as I said, it works perfectly with normal, non-protected content.

Comment: Audio is often not encrypted even with an encrypted video. The results you are seeing can happen when the request for the decryption key fails or the response indicates that the key is not been granted. This would usually show something in the logs if it were a regular player. I'm nit sure if you are able to test the same video in a HTML5 DRM test page like Shaka and confirm the the license if being sent correctly: https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/demo/#audiolang=en-us;textlang=en-us;uilang=en-us;panel=HOME;build=uncompiled

Comment: Yeah, I can see the video inside Shaka Player. The problem is that I actually want to copy the video's texture to a WebGL texture. As far as I understand, DRM textures are protected and you can't actually access them (unlike normal videos, that are working well).

Comment: @DiBV, yes that's correct, if the DRM is working correctly it should not be possible to copy like that.

Comment: Hm okey, if there is no support for protected textures in WebGl then there is nothing to be done. Thank you @Mick.